# Python is, == operator precedence

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-precedence, nonetype

In Python3,

```
a = b = 3
a is None == b is None
```

returns False, but

```
(a is None) == (b is None)
```

returns True. So I would assume based on this example alone, == has precedence over *is*.

However,

```
a = b = None
a is None == b is None
```

returns True. And

```
(a is None) == (b is None)
```

returns True. But

```
a is (None == b) is None
```

returns False. In this case, it would seem as if *is* has precedence over ==.

To give another example, and this expression isn't meant to do anything, but bear with me please. If I say

```
None is None == None
```

it returns True. But both of the following return False.

```
None is (None == None)
(None is None) == None
```

So clearly, Python isn't evaluating these with some strict precedence, but I'm confused what is going on. How is it evaluating this expression with 2 different operators, but differently from either order?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you see here is **operator chaining** and there is no precedence involved at all!

Python supports expressions like

```
1 < a < 3
```

To test that a number is in between 1 and 3; it's equal to `(1 < a) and (a < 3)` except that `a` is only evaluated once.

Unfortunately that also means that e.g.

```
None is None == None
```

actually means

```
(None is None) and (None == None)
```

which is of course True, and the longer example you started with

```
a = b = 3
a is None == b is None
```

means

```
(a is None) and (None == b) and (b is None)
```

which can only be `True` if both `a` and `b` are `None`.

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), see the bit about chaining.

Very useful sometimes but it also pops up when you least expect it!

Comment: I think the more useful example is their original confusing code: `a is None == b is None`, which translates to `a is None and None == b and b is None`. Looked at that way, it's clear that in general, that test only passes if both `a` and `b` are `None`, not if the "`None`ness" of `a` matches that of `b` (which is what the OP intended).

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, all [python comparisons operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) has same priority:

> There are eight comparison operations in Python. They all have the
>   same priority (which is higher than that of the Boolean operations).

However by wrapping comparisons with the brackets, they start to be the [atoms expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atoms), so statements in brackets evaluated before statements outside, that impacts the order of the evalutation, I will decompose the first "contradictional" case, the all others is similar:

```
a = b = 3
a is None == b is None
```

Per documentation the priority is the same, so evaluation is next:

```
1. a is None ? -> False # Because a == 3
2. False == b -> False # Because b == 3
3. False is None
```

Please see order for the second case below:

```
(a is None) == (b is None)

1. a is None ? -> False # Because a == 3
2. b is None -> False # Because b == 3
3. False is False -> True
```