# Why "'y'<'x'==False" "'y'<'x'==True" and always return False?

Tags: python

Why the following statements always return False?

```
>>> 'y'<'x'==True

False

>>> 'y'<'x'==False

False
```

Environment: python 3.6

Comment: Hm, I think my last comment was wrong/misleading. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045377/python-is-operator-precedence) for example.

Comment: Relevant [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons): "x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z"

Comment: `'y'<'x'==True` is parsed as `('y'<'x') and ('x'==True)`

Answer (score 0):

('y' < 'x') == False returns True

Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, < and == have the same precedence.

Comment: That is correct. The second comparison ('x'==False) runs first and it returns False.