# How to tell Django model that only one or other field must be not empty?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

With Django models.Model class like that:

```
class OrderLign(models.Model):
    Order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, blank=True, default=0, null=True)
    Pack = models.ForeignKey(Pack,on_delete=models.RESTRICT, blank=True, default=0,
                             null=True)
```

I need that is possible to save OrderLign only if Item OR Pack is set, not both, and not neither.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add override the [**`clean()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) to check this.

Furthermore we can add database constraints with [Django's constraint API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/) and work with a [**`CheckConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint). If the database supports this, it will reject entries where the two `ForeignKey`s are none, or if both are no `None`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import Q

class OrderLign(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    pack = models.ForeignKey(
        Pack,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.item is None) == (self.pack is None):
            raise ValidationError('item or pack should be filled in')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(item=None, pack__isnull=False) |
                      Q(pack=None, item__isnull=False),
                name='one of the two not null'
            )
        ]
```

Comment: `item=None, pack__isnull=True` doesn't that mean both are null? I think you wanted to write something like `item__isnull=False, pack__isnull=True`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes that was a typo, need more caffeine :)

Comment: @Ahima: normally fields are written in `snake_case`, not `PerlCase`, or `camelCase`, so I would advise to rename `Item` to `item`, `Pack` to `pack`, etc. This makes it less confusing since then there is a `.pack` attribute, and that is related to the `Pack` model.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AbdulAzizBarkat it's what i want !
Is it normal that i have a server error when i try to add a commandLign with Item AND Pack instead a simple form's error ?
``IntegrityError at /admin/front/order/8/change/

new row for relation "front_orderlign" violates check constraint "Seul un article OU un pack peut être liée à une seule et mê"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (46, 210.00, 17, 8, 1, , , PER, 0).
``

Comment: @Ahima: you can `try`-`except` the `IntegrityError`, and raise a `ValueError` in that case in your form.

Comment: Ok @WillemVanOnsem, I used to write the fields in camelcase ONLY for the field referring to another object, not for the other but I understand your advise, thanks

Comment: @Ahima: well one of the main problems could be that if you have *two* fields that refer to the `Foo` model, if you name the first one `Foo`, than the latter will not refer to the model, but to the `ForeignKey` field, and this will result in an exception.

Comment: Maybe i have the server error because my code is wrong ?
I have used the @AbdulAzizBarkat with the correction commented by Willem : 
``constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(Item__isnull=True, Pack__isnull=False) | Q(Pack__isnull=True, Item__isnull=False),
                name='Seul un article OU un pack peut être liée à une seule et même ligne commande.'
            )
        ]``

Comment: @Ahima: well this will raise an `IntegrityException`, and you can handle this in the form/view by rendering the error on the page, or raise a `ValidationException in the form.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I renamed all my class propertie's with the recommandations of PEP like you propose me.
I do not understand how to apply you'r advise for handle the validationError.
This is for my backoffice (admin), i don't have a form.py or a view.
I have tried that in Orderlign Class:
`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`
` if self.item and self.pack:`
`self.item = None`
`self.pack = None`
`raise ValidationError("Only Item or Pack can be add to the OrderLign")`
`return super(OrderLign, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @Ahima: I think then it is better done in the *view*(s) where you create/update the `OrderLine`s. You can call `my_order_line.full_clean()` to obtain the validation errors.

Comment: I don't have *view*(s) where i created/updated the `OrderLign`.
For now I just try to that work in administration of Django in the self-generated standar form of `Order` with `Orderlign` display in `StackedInline`

Comment: @Ahima: normally that will work for a standard `ModelForm`, since it calls the `.clean()` method.

Comment: But in the `save` method of `OrderLign` the lign `raise ValidationError("erro text")` do not sendback an error in the form but direclty a server error `ValidationError at /admin/front/order/1/change/`

Comment: @Ahima: correct, and a `ModelForm` will call `.clean()` and if that raises a `ValidationError`, it will see this as an error of the form, so `form.is_valid()` will be false, and the error will be part of the `form.errors`. You thus should *not* call `.clean()` directly, but let the *modelform* do that.

Comment: Clean method work perfetcly in case where i don't chose Item AND Pack.
The problem come when i try to add `item` AND `pack`

Comment: @Ahima: can you edit your question with the `print((form.instance.item, form.instance.pack))` of the model it is constructing?

Comment: @Ahima: It is also not very clear to me what cases should be rejected, I assumed that *exactly* one should not be `null`. So it should raise an exception if *both* are `NULL`, or if no item is `NULL`.

Comment: Yes is that, exactly one should not be null. 
You ask me for " can you edit your question with the print((form.instance.item, form.instance.pack)) of the model it is constructing? "
I don't now how, i don't have a variable form anywhere, for now i develop the administration part of django with standar `site-packages` forms.
So, I have to customise my OrderLign form to do that ?

Comment: @Ahima: can you share the *view* where you are creating/updating elements. It is hard to diagnose a problem without any information about what it is doing.

Comment: I don't have view or form.
This error comes when i use the standar edit form of Order in the administration of django (the back office).
I use the back office that it was automatically generated by django, i didn't make custom view or form for it (and i don't know how to do that)

Comment: I just have the class in models.py and the file admin.py with 
`class OrderItemInline(admin.StackedInline):`
`model = OrderLign`
`extra = 0`
and
`class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):`
`inlines = [OrderItemInline]`

`admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)`

Comment: I have solved my problem the lign : `if self.item is not None and self.pack is not None:`
`raise ValidationError('Une ligne commande ne peut avoir un article ET un pack')`
in the method clean
Thanks for help

Comment: @Ahima: I found my mistake, you can rewrite the condition to `(a is None) == (b is None)`. the priority of the operators in the `if` case was thus incorrect.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem learned something new from this. It's not operator precedence which is the problem, it is operator chaining as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045377/python-is-operator-precedence I didn't know you could chain `is` and `==` though, seems to be a pretty weird feature to me.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem with some modification to the response of abdul-aziz-barkat and help of Willem.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import Q

class OrderLign(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "ligne commande"
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(item__isnull=True, pack__isnull=False) | Q(pack__isnull=True, item__isnull=False),
                name='Seul un article OU un pack peut être liée à une seule et même ligne commande.'
            )
        ]

def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.item is None and self.pack is None:
        raise ValidationError('Une ligne commande doit forcemment avoir un article OU un pack')
    if self.item is not None and self.pack is not None:
        raise ValidationError('Une ligne commande ne peut avoir un article ET un pack')
    return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

That work fine, with this code you can exlusively add an `Orderlign` with an `item` OR a `pack`

Comment: Uhh, I didn't answer your question, you seem to have mistaken me with Willem. (I only commented about a likely typo Willem made in their answer).

Comment: Use English please.